# Is it legal to pretend to be under a certain age to catch pedophiles

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom

I have been in alot of trouble with police lately doing illegal actions to catch criminals. I was thinking of trying something else but I want to make sure that it is legal to do this stuff and what I need to avoid.

I've been watching alot of YouTube videos of people catching pedophiles in person through online communication. I want to do similar but stay on the right side of the law.

So is it legal to pretend to be an age you are not on websites that require you to be a certain age. Although this may breech their terms and conditions will it be enough to get me in trouble with the police.

Also when looking for pedophiles what do I need to be aware of. When does it go too far and what should I avoid doing to not get myself into trouble but to gather as much evidence against a person

*Living in the UK BTW*

Comment: Just to state the obvious...you know who else pretends to be underage to get into places where kids are? **Pedophiles.** Legality aside, you're setting off the very same alarm bells they do, so don't be surprised if/when you get attention from the cops.

Comment: @cHao Just realised that... Gonna be alot harder to work out who i will be actually talking to

Comment: @cHao Remember what happened to that catch a predator show? Didn't they get in legal trouble for that same thing? It's like entrapment or something. So even if you catch them it doesn't count. But maybe it was entrapment because the police were involved. If Racing121 is working alone is that entrapment? I'm asking you cHao because you've been kicking ass lately

Comment: What will you do? If you are actually of age, and the alleged pedophile is of age, it seems you can both consent to sexually explicit discussion or acts. The most you could do is embarass them, but it might be embarassing for you, too.

Comment: @LateralTerminal: If the show got in trouble, it was probably for sending explicit messages while posing as a kid. That could very easily be considered entrapment -- i mean, there's a pedo trying to control his urges, and some "13 year old" is pushing all the right buttons...

Comment: @cHao 'there's a pedo trying to control his urges, and some "13 year old" is pushing all the right buttons' is that where it becomes an issue because that is what I thought I would get in trouble for... Still being a teen I know how people fall into this

Comment: @RACING121: It becomes an issue if your actions can be construed as tempting a pedo to do something he wasn't already intending to do. There's lots of grey areas, but if you want one big bright red line, you don't get to initiate the conversation, neither in general nor about anything sexual. All the first moves have to be the pedo's. And if he says he doesn't feel right about it, you are done. No pushing the issue.

Comment: @Brandin UK courts have held that laws against child grooming do not need an actual child, as long as the perpetrator has the necessary criminal intent.

Comment: @richardb, on the other hand, at least in the US, they do require that the person doing the grooming believe that they are talking to an actual child.  There was a case locally a few years back where the police made a big fuss about having busted an "internet predator" who'd shown up at the hotel room with an impressive collection of bondage gear, only for the prosecutor to decline to press charges after looking at the actual messages he'd sent.  The guy quite clearly believed he was talking to an adult posing as a 12-year-old.

Comment: @Mark Wondering if there are any cases where police officers first talked to each other and then tried to arrest each other...